# Can I control mouse in Electron?

Tags: javascript, electron

I want just move the mouse to a specific location relative to my App Window.

I don't find a way to achieve this behavior, is that even possible?

Comment: This query doesn't seems to relate with any code or program. Kindly add what you have tried so that we can help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out [RobotJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/robotjs), it should do just fine in your case. From its docs:

```
// Move the mouse across the screen as a sine wave.
var robot = require("robotjs");

// Speed up the mouse.
robot.setMouseDelay(2);

var twoPI = Math.PI * 2.0;
var screenSize = robot.getScreenSize();
var height = (screenSize.height / 2) - 10;
var width = screenSize.width;

for (var x = 0; x < width; x++)
{
    y = height * Math.sin((twoPI * x) / width) + height;
    robot.moveMouse(x, y);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

See [WebContents.prototype.sendInputEvent](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/web-contents.md#webcontentssendinputeventevent)

Example:

```
remote.getCurrentWebContents().sendInputEvent({type: 'mouseMove', x: 10, y: 10})
```

Comment: This will emulate a moving mouse event to the application, but not actually move the mouse.

Comment: It's as close as you can get with electron, you could always shell out to `xdo` or similar tools.